# Accessing Active Directory Role Membership through LDAP using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, active-directory, ldap, linked-server

I would like to get a list of Active Directory users along with the security groups they are members of using SQL Server 2005 linked servers. I have the query working to retrieve records but I'm not sure how to access the memberOf attribute (it is a multi-value LDAP attribute).

I have this temporary to store the information:

```
DROP TABLE #ADUSERGROUPS
CREATE TABLE #ADUSERGROUPS 
(
sAMAccountName varchar(30),
UserGroup varchar(50)
)
```

Each group/user association should be one row.

This is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT sAMAccountName,memberOf
FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, '<LDAP://hqdc04/DC=nt,DC=avs>;
                (&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=9695)(sn=*)(mail=*)(userAccountControl=512));
                sAMAccountName,memberOf;subtree')
```

I get this error msg:

> OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'ADSDSOObject' IRowset::GetData returned 0x40eda:  Data status returned from the provider: [COLUMN_NAME=memberOf STATUS=DBSTATUS_E_CANTCONVERTVALUE], [COLUMN_NAME=sAMAccountName STATUS=DBSTATUS_S_OK]].
>   Msg 7346, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Could not get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider 'ADSDSOObject'. Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation that cannot be directly overcome: - [TSQL: How to get a list of groups that a user belongs to in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766061/tsql-how-to-get-a-list-of-groups-that-a-user-belongs-to-in-active-diretory). OpenQuery cannot handle multi-valued attributes.

I ended up writing a .NET CLR job to handle this.