# AD Principal groups count error

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm working in C# pulling active directory groups for users. For some reason the app is throwing an error for one user on the following code snippet

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetGroups();
int total = groups.Count();
```

Error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

I have never seen a `Count()` method throw this kind of error before.

Comment: can you show how you Instantiating the Principal Object.. I think that may be one of the reasons it's failing. for example in order to get groups you need to get the users first one would think like so `UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(...);` here is something that you can look at to get better example of how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net

Comment: Did you check that the `groups` results isn't `NULL` ??

Comment: @marc_s That was my first thought, but then you'd expect to see a `NullReferenceException` instead of an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, no...?

Comment: @rsbarro: you're probably right on that one! :-)

Comment: Similar problem mentioned in the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846097/active-directories-userprincipal-current-getgroups-returns-group-on-local-not

Comment: PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomain, ADDomain + "\\" + ADUser, ADPassword);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, ntID);

Comment: kerberos isn't much of an option...

Comment: I discovered groups in an unknown state which caused this error. Very weird - but if the user had such groups in their MemberOf attribute, a foreach or converting ToList would throw an exception