# Complex SQL to see roles from groups?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ldap

First post....
I'm trying to map roles to LDAP group membership and hoped I could get some help with how to analyse this please?

A role consists of between 1 and 12 groups from a set of 12 groups.
A role can only have a particular group once.
I think a user may have more than one role, they probably shouldn't but they might.  Example:

Role | Group(s)
Helpdesk | Password Reset
Security | Password Reset, Enable User
Reception | Enable User, Disable User

The data I have is of the form

User | Group
SmithA | Password Reset
SmithA | Enable User
BloggsJ | Password Reset
MouseM | Enable User
MouseM | Disable User

From that you can see the users have the following roles
User | Role
SmithA | Security
BloggsJ | Helpdesk
MouseM | Reception

I can modify the first table anyway that makes it more useful e.g split the groups over multiple rows such as the example below:

Role | Group(s)
Helpdesk | Password Reset
Security | Password Reset
Security | Enable User
Reception | Enable User
Reception | Disable User

I'm struglling with the SQL needed to build a list of User's Roles and have a horrible feeling I'm missing the obvious. 
I'm using MS Access and this isn't a homework assignment :)
Thanks

Comment: All kinds of joins and unions, none of which even remotely work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to look at LDAP.  I got ideas from ---

' [TSQL: How to get a list of groups that a user belongs to in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766061/tsql-how-to-get-a-list-of-groups-that-a-user-belongs-to-in-active-diretory)

' for information only, to get list of domains used in the GetObject calls
' run this first to see whats out there

```
Dim objNameSpace
Dim Domain
Set objNameSpace = GetObject("WinNT:")
For Each Domain In objNameSpace
   Debug.Print Domain.Name
Next
Exit   ' comment out after first time.
```

The weekly routine

```
' initialize   needs reference   Excel 
Dim rc As Long, sFile As String, xls As Excel.Application
' your routine to get an output file name  as sFile
' your routine to create XLS app and open an empty workbook named sFile and make sheet name


' add column headings in row 1
Dim nRow As Long, nCol As Long
Dim sHeading As Variant, myHeadings() As Variant: myHeadings = Array("User", "Group", "yourField3", "yourField4", "Count")
nRow = 1
nCol = 0
For Each sHeading In myHeadings
    nCol = nCol + 1
    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(1, nCol) = myHeadings(nCol - 1)
Next sHeading

' needs reference   "Active DS Type Library"
Dim sGroup As Variant, myGroups() As Variant: myGroups = Array("yourGroup1", "yourGroup2")
' get each group
For Each sGroup In myGroups

    Dim IGroup1 As IADsGroup, IUser1 As IADsUser
    Set IGroup1 = GetObject("WinNT://" & "yourDomain" & "/" & sGroup & ",group")

    ' get each user in that group
    For Each IUser1 In IGroup1.Members

        If (Mid$(IUser1.Name, 1, 6) <> "userToBypass") Then

            Dim IGroup2 As IADsGroup, IUser2 As IADsUser
            Set IUser2 = GetObject("WinNT://" & "yourDomain" & "/" & IUser1.Name & ",user")

            ' get each group for that user
            For Each IGroup2 In IUser2.Groups

                If (Mid$(UCase(IGroup2.Name), 1, 13) <> "GroupToBypass") Then
                    nRow = nRow + 1
                    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(nRow, "A") = IUser2.Name
                    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(nRow, "B") = IGroup2.Name
                    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(nRow, "C") = "yourField3"
                    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(nRow, "D") = "yourField4" ' e.g. IUser2.Role ??
                    xls.ActiveSheet.cells(nRow, "E") = 1
                End If
            Next IGroup2

        End If
    Next IUser1
Next sGroup

' IADs cleanup
Set IGroup2 = Nothing
Set IUser2 = Nothing
Set IGroup1 = Nothing
Set IUser1 = Nothing
```

Now you have it in Excel, and you can do PIVOT or filter or just list

1/25 early am  -- AHA, please ignore the above code as I thought you were going to LDAP to get this info.  But since its already in a table, and lets use the following SQL --

```
SELECT UserGroup.User, UserGroup.Group, RoleGroup.Role
FROM UserGroup LEFT JOIN RoleGroup ON UserGroup.Group = RoleGroup.Group
ORDER BY UserGroup.User, RoleGroup.Role;
```

It returns--

```
User    Group           Role
BloggsJ Password Reset  Helpdesk
BloggsJ Password Reset  Security
MouseM  Disable User    Reception
MouseM  Enable User     Reception
MouseM  Enable User     Security
SmithA  Password Reset  Helpdesk
SmithA  Enable User     Reception
SmithA  Enable User     Security
SmithA  Password Reset  Security
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for taking the time to reply but I'm not sure how your answer relates to the question.  I already have all the groups from the LDAP, now I need to relate them to the roles we have defined (external to the LDAP) it's a data processing question. Thanks

Comment: Where are the   Role | Group(s)    stored?  Is that a short list external to the system? and could be added as a "constants" list in the above program?  Or are they stored in the system, in which case a "join" or "lookup" on them could be done?

Comment: They can be stored anywhere we want them too.  Currently I have two tables in a DB.  The LDAP data, columns are USER | GROUP and the second table are the roles GROUP | ROLE.  Please describe the SQL to generate USER | ROLE using the example data above.

Comment: I have modified the above answer and added the SQL at the end, with is resultset.

Comment: Ah....I can see part of the problem :) I was being too led by the real world process.  A user requests a role, let's say "Security".  To grant that they get added to two groups, "Password Reset" and "Enable User".  I was trying to write SQL that would return only "Security" and not "Helpdesk" (note Helpdesk has the "Password Reset" group) but that's daft and in fact I do want to highlight they're in the other role too even if wasn't requested.

Comment: ....BUT...  in the result set above SmithA is shown as having the "Reception" role. That's not correct, he has the "Enable User" group but not "Disable User"....so it's not quite as simple as that join.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it....I think...amazing what hot water on your head in the shower does.  a) count the number of rows for each role type from the roles table.  b) do the join on group between the role and LDAP table.  c) count the number of times a distinct user appears per role.  d) if that count is the same as the count of groups per role then it's a match.

I'll code it up later, got to tile a roof now.